# Blank screen after logging out of XFCE

Tags: arch-linux, xfce, logout

I have a fresh install of Arch Linux with a few packages, including XFCE. I started XFCE using startxfce4, then used XFCE to Log Out. But now all I have is a blank screen. How can I get my prompt back?

Comment: You could try to switch to tty1 by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1 and then switch back to tty7 (assuming you have X there) by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F7. Does this bring your graphical login prompt back?

Comment: @RistoSalminen - that is how I fix my problem, which is similar: in Xubuntu/XFCE, clicking "Log Out..." (which should bring me to a panel of options) instead freezes the screen. Anything I do/click/whatever will happen when I switch to a tty and back. That's not a real solution though, since the prompt worked for me in 13.04 - how can we fix this properly?

Comment: Okay, then I probably have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: Is "Blank Screen" means a static wallpaper without anything else or black screen?